# Detect how many pixels scrolled from current position on page, not just top of document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I want the standard UX thing of changing something on scroll :) and I am using this jQuery so far:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 50) {
        $(".search-bar").removeClass('open');
        $(".search-bttn").removeClass('close');
    }
});
```

This changes classes after 50px have been scrolled from the top of the document, is it possible to change the class after 50px have been scrolled from anywhere on the page?

The UX explanation for this is that I have a position:fixed search bar appearing after a click function opens it, and then I want it to disapear after scroll, but I dont want it to disappear after 1px is scrolled because it is quite easy to scroll a couple of pixels by accident, I want to say only remove it after 50 or so pixels.

Hope that makes sense! Hopefully someone can lend some insight into this...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on click event, after the search bar open code you can get and store scroll position value in one variable. and then on a scroll, you can compare the new value of scroll after scrolling with that variable.

```
var oldScrollposition = 0;
$("#ClickControl").on("click",function(){
  $(".search-bar").addClass('open');
  oldScrollposition =  $(document).scrollTop();
});

$(document).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(scroll < oldScrollposition )
      scroll = oldScrollposition -scroll; // If scroll down
    else
      scroll = scroll - oldScrollposition; // If scroll Up

    if (scroll >= 50) {
       $(".search-bar").removeClass('open');
       $(".search-bttn").removeClass('close');
    }
});
```

Change click control id according to your.

Comment: Epic! That worked like a charm! Thanks for your help :)